# What does Translation property from an IFC mean?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

We are translating from IFC coordinates to forge viewer coordinates by using following formula: `forgeX = ifc.X - (globalOffset.x - translation.x);` where `translation.x` is coming from the forge properties (see below) and `globalOffset` is the forge viewer's calculated offset. (E.g. we are using this value to translate the IfcElevation to forge viewer coordinates).

1. However, can we rely that this will always hold true?
2. Sometimes the translation properties do not exist for an translated IFC. When does an IFC has translation properties?

```json
{
  "objectid": 1,
  "name": "FILENAME.ifc",
  "externalId": "a",
  "properties": {
    "IFC Properties": {
      "IFC Application Name": "ARCHICAD",
      "IFC Application Version": "23.0.0",
      "IFC Organization": "GRAPHISOFT",
      "IFC Schema": "IFC2X3",
      "IFC Time Stamp": "2020-01-06 16:23:29 +00:00",
      "Name": "IFC Properties"
    },
    "Item": {
      "Hidden": "No",
      "Icon": "File",
      "Material": "",
      "Name": "FILENAME.ifc",
      "Required": "No",
      "Translation.X": "0.000 ft",
      "Translation.Y": "0.000 ft",
      "Translation.Z": "131.463 ft",
      "Type": "File",
      "Unit": "Feet"
    },
    "Location": {
      "Elevation": "0.000 ft",
      "Latitude": "52.517",
      "Longitude": "13.400",
      "Name": "Location Data",
      "ProjectLocation": "Internal",
      "Timezone": "1.000"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I cannot reproduce the `Translation` properties with my own IFC models and cannot find any related properties on either spec of IfcSite or IfcProject. So, could you consider sharing a minimum none-confidential reproducible model to `forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com`? If so, I can consult our IFC-related engineering team for insights. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that Forge translates custom IfcProperties? I am guessing the CAD application exports some custom translation property.

Comment: Maybe, but it's hard to tell without a reference... I'm trying to get the properties with my couple of IFC files. Unfortunately, they don't have such properties. Could you try to convert an IFC containing `Translation` properties from either of ArchiCAD's sample models from your side? It will help us understand what it is more quickly. We appreciate your cooperation and understanding.

Comment: I replied to the corresponding support ticket with an example IFC.